# UWP MapLocationFinder always returning InvalidCredentials

Tags: c#, uwp

In a plain UWP app, I am trying to use MapLocationFinder.FindLocationsAsync().
It always returns InvalidCredentials.
I tried recreating a new Bing Maps key and apply it using MapService.ServiceToken = "Bing Maps key" prior to calling he FindLocationAsync() but nothing changes.
Tried on two different machines. No difference.
The existing answers have not resolved the issue (they mainly pointed to setting the MapService.ServiceToken which I already do).
Any other ideas ?

Comment: Please share some more code for better context.

Comment: I could not reproduce your issue with a correct [maps authentication](https://www.bingmapsportal.com/Application). Please check if the key has expired.

Comment: ​The issue was caused by the Bing Maps Developer Site. It appears as if some maintenance or a change was going on while I generated the keys over the weekend. Today (Monday), two new application types showed up in the Bing Maps key generation site and that solved the issue. So this was neither a UWP nor a Visual Studio problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

​The issue was caused by the Bing Maps Developer Site. It appears as if some maintenance or a change was going on while I generated the keys over the weekend. Today (Monday), two new application types showed up in the Bing Maps key generation site (Private / Public Windows UWP, 8,x or earlier) and that solved the issue. So this was neither a UWP, Visual Studio or code problem.